# Why won't my decimal values convert to 6,4?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a bunch of decimal values in a column of a query result that are all in this format:

```
_._ _ _ _ _ _
```

(1 integer before the decimal point, 6 integers after the decimal point)

It is possible for a value in the column to be NULL.

Here are some examples of these values:

```
4.010000
3.800000
1.260000
0.650000
0.010000
0.000000
NULL
```

When I change the select statement in my query to cast the values in this column to decimal(6,4), I get this error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
```

Why am I getting this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Those values do not pose a problem or cause that error. What is the datatype of the column you are selecting from? And what is the MAX value in that field? Anything with 3 digits on the left of the decimal point (i.e. values starting at 100.000) will cause that error.

Comment: @joey Kleingers, you seem to have some value i.e greater than 999.999, so you can't convert to decimal(6,4) , get the max value and check

Comment: I unfortunately cannot post the code, but I have the values in descending order. There are two values that are not in the format that I listed above (886.000000 and 59.530000). I excluded both of these rows from the query and now my descending list goes from 4.010000 to 0.000000 and then NULLs for the rest of the rows at the very end. Yet when I change my query to convert all the integers to decimal(6,4), I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted values in the question (including the `NULL`) *do* convert to `DECIMAL(6, 4)`. That error is coming from a value that is >= 100.

For example, the following all succeed:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 4), 4.010000)
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 4), 3.800000)
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 4), 1.260000)
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 4), 0.650000)
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 4), 0.010000)
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 4), 0.000000)
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 4), NULL)
```

Now try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 4), 100)
```

And you will get:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
```

`DECIMAL(6, 4)` means: 6 total digits, 4 of which are to the right of the decimal.
Hence: **XX.YYYY**
Max Value: **99.9999**

So either try:

- DECIMAL(7, 4) to get another digit to the left of the decimal while still keeping 4 to the right of it
- DECIMAL(6, 3) to maintain 6 total digits but losing one place to the right of the decimal in order to get an extra one to the left of it.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot post the code, but I have the values in descending order.  There are two values that are not in the format that I listed above (886.000000 and 59.530000).  I excluded both of these rows from the query and now my descending list goes from 4.010000 to 0.000000 and then NULLs for the rest of the rows at the very end.  Yet when I change my query to convert all the integers to decimal(6,4), I still get the same error.

Comment: I am using this piece of code in my select statement:

CAST(L.USERCHAR4 AS decimal(6, 4))

I thought that maybe the SELECT gets executed before the WHERE, which would mean that it's still including the 886.000000 number, but apparently the WHERE clause does execute first so that can't be the issue.

Comment: @JoeyKleingers : actually yes, it _can_ be the query optimizer pushing those values through prior to the filter operation. Lemme try something. PS: 59.530000 should be fine for DECIMAL(6, 4). It is only the 886 value that is the issue.

Comment: Interesting.  Any ideas on how to fix it other than changing the value/removing the row?  I was so confused, because after the filter I have a list of values that should be able to be converted, but it was still giving me that error.  Even though I checked the largest and smallest values in a separate "sanity check" query and they converted just fine.

Comment: @JoeyKleingers : great. Try adding `TRY_` to the left of the `CONVERT` so that it is: `TRY_CONVERT`. If that works I will update my answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a value greater than `99.9999` which covers 6 digits total including decimal places

Get the maximum value from the table and check the total decimal places and then try to CONVERT it to fit that maximum value.

```
SELECT MAX(data) FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188791.aspx)

```
When SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT is ON, an error is generated after a loss of 
precision occurs in an expression. When OFF, losses of precision do not 
generate error messages and the result is rounded to the precision of the 
column or variable storing the result.
```

The following:

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 4), 4.010000)
```

generates the error that you have reported. I am just stating this as a possible cause
of the problem.

Comment: This is potentially the problem, but the default setting is `OFF` so I guess we need to wait and see what the OP's max value is ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, where you have 886 in your table, you could use the following query instead.

```
Select Convert(Decimal(20,4), YourColumn)
From   YourTable
Where   YourColumnIs NULL 
    OR (
            Convert(Decimal(20,4), YourColumn) < 10 
            And 
            Convert(Decimal(20,4), YourColumn) > -10
        )
```

If the data type of the column is already a numeric data type, you could remove the convert function in the where clause.

Also, note that I use "< 10" in the where clause because it seems like that is what you want, but you could change this to "< 100" and still only get values that can be converted to decimal(6,4).